# In search of the proper Union DST with inverse-ackermann complexity

Tags: algorithm, kruskals-algorithm, union-find, disjoint-union

I am talking about the [union-find-disjoint data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). There are multiple resources on the internet about how to implement this. So far, I have learnt of two optimization techniques for unions. The first one is 'balancing' the tree by a variable Rank, which says how deep the deepest node is, and therefore is the upper bound on find(). The second optimization is: setting an object's parent to be the head node, while calling find() (the setting also includes the object's parents, so it becomes a cascade of optimizations).

However, when implementations use the two of them at once, they usually merge the two together without much thought. Specifically, [GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-2-kruskals-minimum-spanning-tree-mst/) (just as an example, nothing personal) does this. Wouldn't this lead to the ranks getting "corrupted" and O(log n) complexity?

For example, if I have a long line of nodes (5 to 4 to 3 to 2 to 1 to 0, which is the head) and I call find() to 2, the rank stays 5 even though it should be 3.

Answer (score 2):

In such implementations, ranks are still upper bounds on the heights of the trees.
They may indeed become inexact upper bounds.

The [log* proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_O%28log*n%29_time_complexity_of_union%E2%80%93find) does not seem to rely on exactness of that upper bound.

In Tarjan's 1975 article "Efficiency of a Good But Not Linear Set Union Algorithm" linked at the bottom of the above page, he seems to use union-by-size instead of union-by-rank.
The size (number of vertices), unlike the exact rank, is easy to maintain in O(1) operations per union.

Comment: So the real point of union-by-rank is lowering the upper bound? Union-by-size gives log* n complexity, right?

Comment: @ReaLNero Tarjan seems to prove inverse-Ackermann upper bound for union-by-size in that 1975 article. Perhaps the same upper bound is true for union-by-rank. As for why people nowadays tend to use rank instead of size, I don't know. Maybe because it can be stored using less bits, and is cheaper to compute.

Comment: Short question: When merging two components, should I update the size as the sum of both, or just do the usual(shorter to longer, if equal - increment size)?

Comment: @ReaLNero The new **size** is the number of vertices, i.e., the sum of both sizes. The new **rank** is the largest of the two ranks, plus one if they were equal. You can use any one of these characteristics. Either way, the right strategy is to merge the lesser one into the greater.

Answer (score 0):

Rank is not a strict measure of depth. From Wikipedia:

> the term rank is used instead of depth since it stops being equal to the depth if path compression (...) is also used

Note also that the example you give cannot occur. There is no order of unions that will result in a string of single nodes when using union by rank. In fact, a tree with rank r will have at least 2<sup>r</sup> nodes (easily proved with induction). It is also unclear to me how you arrive at the conclusions that a rank that is "too large" will lead to logarithmic complexity.

Comment: Well what is the rank then?

Comment: An upper bound on the depth of the tree.